Implement pagination on accounts with large number of transactions
I need to display accounts as headings with a numerous transactions listed under each account in Laravel. I have two tables: one for accounts and another for transactions. The goal is to retrieve a limited number of transactions for each account efficiently.
Currently, I use the following relation in the Account model:
$this->hasMany('App\Models\Transaction', 'account_id', 'id');

The query I'm using is:
$transactions = Account::with('transactions')->where('store_id', $store_id)->paginate(5);

This gives me pagination for the accounts table, but what I really need is to display the account names and load transactions for each account in chunks, as loading too many transactions at once is slow when the transaction count is large.
I've been searching for a more efficient solution but haven't found one yet.

Edit your question with what you have tried so far? How DB & relations look like ..

You cannot properly paginate relationships if you use with() you need to do it the other way around: Transaction::whereHas('account' , fn($query) use($store_id)  { $query->where('store_id', $store_id) })->paginate(5) and yes, this has a n+1 query problem lurking :)

and how do you intend to load the next chunk of transactions for a specific account?

Right now, I'm working on how to achieve this. That's why I added the question here.
I need infinite scroll functionality on the front-end side so that users can scroll down, and the records (transactions under each account) will load dynamically.

Just retrieve the accounts informations without the transactions
$accounts = Account::query()->where('store_id', $store_id)->paginate(20);

Then for each account fetch their transactions with infinity scroll on demand in a separate route.
$transactions = Transaction::where('account_id', $accountId)->paginate(20);


The first solution that comes to mind is to show all accounts on the first page, and when the user clicks on an account, load the transactions for that specific account. However, the challenge is that I need to implement this with an infinite loader, where the information is loaded progressively as the user scrolls. This means that I need to display both accounts and their associated transactions at once, without the user having to manually click on an account.

@BasitAlvi So if I understand correctly, you wanna list the Accounts one under the other and under each account line you want an infinity scroll for transactions ? is that correct ? if so, how is the user gonna be able to scroll down to check the last account in the liste ? if he goes down, all the infinity scroll will trigger and send the last account line into infinity.

you can argue that the number of transaction is limited and not infinite, but it is still a bad UX to check the last account in the listing. Hope this gives you some insight into how to show your transactions.

$transactions = Transaction::whereHas('account' , fn($query) use($storeId) { 
        $query->where('store_id', $storeId)
    })
    ->with('account')
    ->paginate(50)

You can directly get the transactions like this and for the account name on the blade page use this
@foreach($transactions as $transaction)
    {{ $transaction->account->name }}
@endforeach


In this solution, the user can view transactions for random accounts without any sequence. What I need is a structured view where each account name is listed first, followed by all its transactions in sequence, ensuring that the order is maintained.
